# How to fixup commits to upper in Git?

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

When rebasing in Git we usually can join (fixup, squash) several commits to bottom one, for instance, `A, B, C -> A'` (here B and C are newer than A). This is not a good practise as you see a *date* of beginning of work (commit A), but not it's finish (commit C). Like you made a feature on 23.09.2019, but not on 25.09.

Now we have several commits and want to fixup A, B, C to C: `A, B, C, D, E -> C', D', E'`. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd proceed like this

```
# We first point to C
git checkout C

# Then we "unpack" changes between A and C into the working tree
git reset --soft A

# Let's now create commit C'
git commit -m "Message for C' (so A,B and C)"

# and finally we just have to bring back copies of D and E
git cherry-pick D E
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried in 'Git Extensions', it works. In the end I had to create a new branch, because it became unattached. When we commit A, B, C commits, we have a new date (current time). Except for this points, everything works right.